# Outlook/SharePoint calendar sync 'error occurred connecting to site'

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, outlook, alternate-access-mapping, task-list, ssl

Our SharePoint site was originally setup under a test name (oldname). When brought into production, I added an AAM to extend it to our production name (prodname). About 6 months ago, I added an SSL redirect in IIS which sends all http requests to https. With the addition of the SSL redirect, Outlook/SharePoint calendar syncing stopped working.

In Outlook, users are getting the error **'Task 'SharePoint' reported error (0x0004010F).  'The SharePoint List (Develop - Calendar) cannot be found  If the problem continues, contact the SharePoint site admin.  HTTP 404.  An error occurred connecting to http://oldname.com/sites/abc/develop.  A connection to http://prodname.com/sites/abc/develop, an alternate Web address for this SharePoint site, will be attempted'**

**Task 'SharePoint' reported error (0x80070005):  'You do not have permission to view this SharePoint List (Develop - Calendar).  Contact the SharePoint site administrator.  HTTP 303.'**

My AAMs look like this for mapping collection: 'oldname.com'

Internal URL      ------         Zone     --------   Public URL for Zone

http://oldname.com  Default         http://oldname.com

http://prodname.com Internet                 http://prodname.com

https://prodname.com    Custom          https://prodname.com

I think I should also have the entry:

http://prodname.com Custom          https://prodname.com

but according to what I've read, I can't have duplicate Internal URLs for the collection yet I also must have an entry where the Internal and Public URLs match.

Or perhaps it's not an AAM issue?  Any advice would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to set up the calendar sync with the appropriate web address using HTTPS. The error is telling you it's trying to connect to `http://oldname.com/sites/abc/develop` which isn't the URL you want configured. As a fallback, it is attempting to pull the calendar from `http://prodname.com/sites/abc/develop`, but that's hitting your HTTP Redirect in IIS.

Configure the calendar overlay using `https://prodname.com/sites/abc/develop` and this issue should be resolved.

Also, make sure that all user accounts requesting the calendar have proper permissions on the calendar list.

Comment: Thank you.  I'm quite sure this is the solution and I've passed the information on to the user but I haven't heard back yet so find out if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Restart your internet connection.

Disable your firewall and antivirus.

Clear your browser cache.

Flush your DNS cache.

Change your DNS servers.

Hope You Find This Useful,

Peter